# CSS select an element in this markup

Tags: html, css

I have following markup, which I cannot change. I want to apply a specific css only to the  which is located at the end of the div, but not to the any which is inside some other div. Is it possible to select it?

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="another">
        <ul>
            <li>not</li>
            <li>this</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>select</li>
        <li>this</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried, `.box ul:last-child` but it doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/7e53A/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7e53A/2/)

```
.box > ul{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

What this means is sort of: *Select an `ul` within `.box` but not any other grand children.*

**@Koushik's comment:** If you have more than one `ul` in your `.box` then you could add `:last-child` to your css:

```
.box > ul:last-child{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: your code will give border color to all the ul inside class .box?... but he is asking only to color last child node

Comment: That's correct, I only matched the code he posted. Updated now.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close. You just have to use the direct child selector `>`.

Useful Article: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

```
.box > ul:last-child{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/7e53A/8/)

Answer (score 0):

sample code to find last node using jquery jquery [code](http://jsfiddle.net/7e53A/14/) and css [code](http://jsfiddle.net/7e53A/11/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( ".box  ul" ).last().css( "color", "red" );

});
```